# UITableViewCell Separator disappearing in iOS15

Tags: swift, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, ios15

I try to add separator line like this.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUhCM.png)

But separator line disappearing when there is no data.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn00F.png)

Can anyone please help me solve this issue?Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In you `viewDidLoad` function add this:

```
yourTableViewReference.fillerRowHeight = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine
```

Answer (score 0):

towa x!
This can be fixed by adding options to Separator. In MainStoryBoard go to the Attributes Inspector/Separator. Change it to Default - separator are shown in any condition: empty or filled.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't even compile!
According to the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3801921-fillerrowheight) you have to set the `fillerRowHeigt` to automaticDimensions.

So the way to write is, to add this line of code to your `viewDidLoad` or to the part where you setup the tableView:

```
tableView.fillerRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

This variable is only available since iOS 15, so to support older versions use:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
   tableView.fillerRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```